# SQL Join duplicates, converting an access db

Tags: php, mysql, join, duplicates

I am converting an access database to a new format. Currently all data resides in MySQL.

For the purposes of this question, there are 3 tables. **tbl_Bills**, **tbl_Documents**, and **tbl_Receipts**.

I wrote an outer join query , as some bills have documents and receipts, other's don't. And I need a full listing of each set, given those situations, to be processed by a php script later on.

The problem is that the primary identifier, we'll call **fld_CommonID**, happens to exist in duplicate. For example, 3 bills have the same identifier, with different information. 3 documents and 3 receipts match those 3 bills. 
So as you might have guessed, my join query results in 9 indistinct rows (6 duplicates), when there should be 3 (one join from each table).  An inner join excludes data that isn't defined in the other table, and so doesn't work for my needs.

SO ...  I'm thinking what I want to do, is update those 3 records in each table (across all rows that have duplicates) such that they have a unique counter id. #1, #2, and #3 respectively, so that I can perform join queries on them uniquely per row.

Is that possible without running php code to select the duplicates ordered by natural table order, followed-by updating them with a counter?
Would you advise that I go that route(scripted) instead of some magical SQL query to do such a thing, if such a query can be made?
Or is it possible to outer join based on natural table order (pretty sure that's impossible)?

Comment: Uh, is your database MS Access or MySQL?  These are not the same.

Comment: MySQL fully, I imported the access database, which doesn't have primary keys on these 3 tables. They are managed using natural table order, the old system was an accde access scripted gui that is being replaced by web software.

Comment: I'm writing a script to solve the problem, and splitting up the queries without joins to map them out manually. So although it's a solution , I am still curious for any answers you experts out there may have for such a situation. Will close it if nothing in a couple days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

writing this answer to simply close the question.

Inner joins would be perfect if there were a way to link duplicate fields in separate tables based on natural order (no primary key). The problem isn't that I lack a query, it's that the database is poorly structured. Which is a problem better solved with code not complex queries.